# Will deviceid saved in iOS keychain be synced across all devices using same iCloud account?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I wanted to have same device id for the device even after re-installing the app. I was planning to save it to keychain and retrieve it every time. 
I want to know if keychain data will get synced across all the devices using the same iCloud email id.

I am using the `keychainwrapper` in this [downloadable_link](https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2014/12/KeychainWrapper.zip).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.

I read that the same UUID will be shared across all devices with same iCloud account.(Not sure about this.)

I had to restrict app login for upto 3 devices for each email id. If keychain data will get synced, then I cannot do this . If I have 3 different iPhones, it will be considered as a single device only if the user uses same icloud account.

After some googleing I came across [SAMKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/SAMKeychain).
It has a property called `synchronizationmode` which I think will do the job of preventing the keychain key /value from syncing it to iCloud.

I use the below code to generate UUID.

```
func UUID() -> String {

        let bundleName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String
        let accountName = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + String(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!.characters.reversed()) // just one extra layer of protection.. :p

        var applicationUUID = SAMKeychain.password(forService: bundleName, account: accountName)

        if applicationUUID == nil {

            applicationUUID = (UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)!

            // Save applicationUUID in keychain without synchronization
            let query = SAMKeychainQuery()
            query.service = bundleName
            query.account = accountName
            query.password = applicationUUID
            query.synchronizationMode = SAMKeychainQuerySynchronizationMode.no

            do {
                try query.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("SAMKeychainQuery Exception: \(error)")
            }
        }

        return applicationUUID!
    }
```

You can check the sample app in swift 3 [here](https://github.com/abhimuralidharan/UniqueUUIDAPP) in GITHUB.If someone has a better answer , Please let me know.

NOTE: SAMKeychain from their official github page was not working properly for me. Please use the one I am using in the [UniqueUUIDAPP](https://github.com/abhimuralidharan/UniqueUUIDAPP). I had to make some code commenting to make it work.